# 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found in react-native 0.72.3

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am a novice in react-native.I  run a existing project and i found this problem.All the solutions i found in google not worked, by the way, my xcode version is 14.3.1, react-native is 0.72.3 , Can someone help me solve it？ i will very  appreciate is. here is my Pod file

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '14.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'AuthCoreWalletDemo' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => false,#flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  
      pod 'AuthCoreAdapter', '0.1.9'
      pod 'ParticleAuthCore', '0.1.9'
      pod 'ParticleMPCCore', '0.1.9'
      pod 'Thresh', '0.1.9'
      
      pod 'ParticleWalletGUI', '1.0.2'
      pod 'ParticleWalletAPI', '1.0.2'
      pod 'ParticleNetworkBase', '1.0.2'
      pod 'ParticleAuthService', '1.0.2'
      pod 'ParticleWalletConnect', '1.0.2'
      pod 'ParticleBiconomy', '1.0.2'
      
      pod 'ParticleConnect',  '0.2.8'
      pod 'ConnectWalletConnectAdapter',  '0.2.8'
      pod 'ConnectEVMAdapter',  '0.2.8'
      pod 'ConnectSolanaAdapter',  '0.2.8'
      pod 'ConnectPhantomAdapter',  '0.2.8'
      pod 'ConnectCommon',  '0.2.8'
      pod 'ParticleAuthAdapter',  '0.2.8'
      
      pod 'SkeletonView', :git => 'https://github.com/SunZhiC/SkeletonView.git', :branch => 'main'
      pod 'SwiftMessages', :git => 'https://github.com/SunZhiC/SwiftMessages', :branch => 'master'

  target 'AuthCoreWalletDemoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)


    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        end
      end
    
    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
    .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
    
    
      installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
             end
        end
      end

        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS'] = 'arm64, arm64e, x86_64'
        end
    end
end
````

want xcode find RCTAppDelegate.h